# Execute code after completing all multiple service call

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular4-httpclient, angular-observable

I need to execute some codes after completing all the service call, because i need data from each of those service calls.
i have my main ts file, service ts file and api controller where db hit will happen.

My main Ts file code

```
    export class demoComponent implements OnInit{
    data1 : any[]
    data2 : any[]
    data3 : any[]

    ngOnInit() {
    this.ServiceComponent.method1(this.id).subscribe((response: Response) => { this.data1 = <any>response, console.log('data', response) });
    this.ServiceComponent.method2(this.id).subscribe((response: Response) => { this.data2 = <any>response, console.log('data', response) });
    this.ServiceComponent.method3(this.id).subscribe((response: Response) => { this.data3 = <any>response, console.log('data', response) });
    .
    .
    some codes to execute...
            }
    }
```

ServiceComponent.ts file

```
public method1 = (id: number): Observable<any> => {return this._http.get(this.method1Url + id).map(response => { return <DataList>response.json() });}
public method2 = (id: number): Observable<any> => {return this._http.get(this.method2Url + id).map(response => { return <DataList>response.json() });}
public method3 = (id: number): Observable<any> => {return this._http.get(this.method3Url + id).map(response => { return <DataList>response.json() });}
```

From the serviceComponent.ts the api controller is called and db hit is made.
The issue am facing is some codes are there after service call which is executing before completing service call and the data is showing undefined because no value is assigned to array.
In jquery  we have operator `$.When()` where all service inside will execute and then proceeds to other code. Is any operator is there in angular 4
Its better after completing all service calls, the code should execute. Need help
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

Answer (score 3):

Use RxJS's Observable forkJoin:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';

// ...

ngOnInit() {
    Observable.forkJoin(
        this.ServiceComponent.method1(this.id),
        this.ServiceComponent.method2(this.id),
        this.ServiceComponent.method3(this.id)
    ).subscribe(response => {
        this.data1 = <any>response[0];
        this.data2 = <any>response[1];
        this.data2 = <any>response[2];
        // Here the codes you want to execute after retrieving all data
     });
}
```

Comment: if those codes are outside the forkJoin() method, then what will happen?

Comment: same approach but i would maybe just consider `zip` operator for this case rather than `forkJoin` because `zip` keeps track of corresponding indexes for `inner observables`. https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/zip.html

Comment: errow is thrown in console on executing the above code   
 {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:49548/api/service/method1?id=4964'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'service' that matches the name 'method1'."}"

Comment: It's a problem of your REST api, ensure URI is correct and exists in your API

Comment: fixed that issue. but still some data is coming as undefined and i tried with zip()

Answer (score 1):

Another option to consider is to define a set of route resolvers. You could set up each method in its own route resolver and then the route won't activate until all resolvers are complete, that is to say that all of the data has been retrieved.

As an example, here is one of my resolvers.

NOTE: It looks a bit complex because it has quite a bit of exception handling. But it could be as simple as just your method call.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

import { IProduct } from './product';
import { ProductService } from './product.service';

@Injectable()
export class ProductResolver implements Resolve<IProduct> {

    constructor(private productService: ProductService,
                private router: Router) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
            state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<IProduct> {
        let id = route.params['id'];
        // let id = route.paramMap.get('id');
        if (isNaN(+id)) {
            console.log(`Product id was not a number: ${id}`);
            this.router.navigate(['/products']);
            return Observable.of(null);
        }
        return this.productService.getProduct(+id)
            .map(product => {
                if (product) {
                    return product;
                }
                console.log(`Product was not found: ${id}`);
                this.router.navigate(['/products']);
                return null;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(`Retrieval error: ${error}`);
                this.router.navigate(['/products']);
                return Observable.of(null);
            });
    }
}
```